# Indirect function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecma262

There are things like

```
f.call(...)
f.apply(...)
```

But then there's this

```
(1, alert)('Zomg what is this????!!!11')
```

"1" does not seem to mean much in this context, the following works just fine:

```
(null, alert)('Zomg what is this????!!!11')
(1, null, alert)('Zomg what is this????!!!11')
(undefined, alert)('Zomg what is this????!!!11')
```

Could you point to a specific part of ECMAScript which describes that syntax?

Comment: Related: [Does the comma operator influence the execution context in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076794/does-the-comma-operator-influence-the-execution-context-in-javascript/36077031#36077031)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are just using [The Comma Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.14).

This operator only evaluates its operands from left to right, and returns the value from the second one, for example:

```
(0, 1); // 1
('foo', 'bar'); // 'bar'
```

In the context of calling a function, the evaluation of the operand will simply get a value, not a reference, this causes that the `this` value inside the invoked function point to the global object (or it will be `undefined` in the new ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode).

For example:

```
var foo = 'global.foo';

var obj = {
  foo: 'obj.foo',
  method: function () {
    return this.foo;
  }
};

obj.method();      // "obj.foo"
(1, obj.method)(); // "global.foo"
```

As you can see, the first call, which is a direct call, the `this` value inside the `method` will properly refer to `obj` (returning `"obj.foo"`), the second call, the evaluation made by the comma operator will make the `this` value to point to the global object (yielding `"global.foo"`).

That pattern has been getting quite popular these days, to make indirect [calls to `eval`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.1.1), this can be useful under ES5 strict mode, to get a reference to the global object, for example, (imagine you are in a non-browser environment, `window` is not available):

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var global = (function () { return this || (1,eval)("this"); })();
})();
```

In the above code, the inner anonymous function will execute within a strict mode code unit, that will result on having the `this` value as `undefined`.

The `||` operator will now take the second operand, the `eval` call, which is an indirect call, and it will evaluate the code on the global lexical and variable environment.

But personally, in this case, under strict mode I prefer using the `Function` constructor to get the global object:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var global = Function('return this')();
})();
```

Functions that are created with the `Function` constructor are strict only if they start with a Use Strict Directive, they don't "inherit" the strictness of the current context as Function Declarations or Function Expressions do.

Comment: Thanks for the ECMAScript link

Comment: Regarding: "will simply get a value, not a reference". That's not what's happening at all. You're seeing different behavior because you're invoking the function without the [dot operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). You'd see the same behavior if you did this: `var temp = obj.method;
temp();`

Comment: @lwburk: I'm talking in terms of the specification, it will get a *value*, not a [Reference](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7), see what the comma operator returns: "Step 4. Return GetValue(rref)." It uses the [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1) abstract operation. The example you post is indeed equivalent, but slightly different, in that case `temp` is a *reference* with no *base object*.

Comment: @lwburk, Ah, also, you can see that your example isn't *exactly* equivalent, in ES5: `eval('foo')` is a [Direct Call to eval](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.1.1), but `(1, eval)('foo')` is not, this case has not to do with the `.` property accessor. Kangax explains this very well [here](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/#indirect_eval_call_theory).

Comment: Very interesting. My point was far more pedestrian: `(1, obj.method) === obj.method // true`

Comment: Analogous `(1, obj.method)();` will be something like `var tmp = obj.method; tmp();` which uses `this === window` in non-strict mode or `this === undefined` in strict mode.

Answer (score 9):

It's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator), which evaluates both of its operands and returns the value of the second one.

So, something like `(null, alert)` evaluates to the `alert` function, which you can immediately call using parentheses.

It's described in section 11.14 of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 3):

The [comma operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b37css7%28VS.85%29.aspx) causes expressions to be evaluated sequentially.  Wrapping the expressions in parentheses returns the value of the last expression.  So `(1, alert)("hello")` is functionally equivalent to:

```
1;
alert("hello");
```

Off the top of my head, I can't think of a reason to do this.