# Is it okay to use with()?

Tags: javascript

Once, I saw an example like this:

```
var a, x, y;
var r = 10;
with (Math) {
  a = PI * r * r;
  x = r * cos(PI);
  y = r * sin(PI / 2);
}
```

And it looks very convenience, because that way I don't have to type all the `Math.`s.

But when I take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description), it says:

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is *forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode*. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

So is it okay to use `with()`? In `HTML5`?

Comment: Define "okay". If you mean "recommended" then no (at least by one good source), and you've quoted the evidence. If you mean "will it work", then maybe, it depends if you are using strict mode or not.

Comment: This question did not deserve a down-vote

Comment: BTW HTML 4 or 5 is irrelevant. Javascript/ECMAScript is not part of HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MDN you linked says `Using with is not recommended`...
`with` is an excellent way of making spaghetti code for lunch.

You might like it, but the guy that will need to debug it will curse you.

`javascript` has some very weird operators, like the comma operator(`,`).
Can you understand what the following code does?

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
a = [b][b = a,0];
```

Well it swaps a and b... You don't understand `,` so as the guy that will need maintain your `with` code. Don't use hacks, hacks are cool in charades games, not in real code.

---

[When is the comma operator useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579546/601179)
[**The comma swap Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr7hJ/1/)

Comment: What the... o.O What do `a = [b][b = a,0];` do?

Comment: I don't get it... `[b][b = a,0]` wtf...is that?

Comment: @Derek. Check the updated fiddle. It swaps `a` and `b`. Now do you understand why am I right...? hacks are cool, but not in a real code!

Comment: Very confusing, and now I really curious that how `[b][b = a,0]` works. :P

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to use any feature of JavaScript, *so long as you understand it*.

For example, using `with` you can access *existing* properties of an object, but you *cannot* create new ones.

Observe:

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
with(obj) {
    a = 3;
    c = 5;
}
// obj is now {a:3,b:2}, and there is a global variable c with the value 5
```

It can be useful for shortening code, such as:

```
with(elem.parentNode.children[elem.parentNode.children.length-3].lastChild.style) {
    backgroundColor = "red";
    color = "white";
    fontWeight = "bold";
}
```

Because the properties of the `style` object already exist.

I hope this explanation is clear enough.

Comment: "It is okay to use any feature of JavaScript, so long as you understand it." … and are the only person who will ever maintain it.

Comment: @Quentin. Funny, I just added that kind of remark to my answer. **lol**

Comment: But why didn't they recommend `with()`?

Comment: Just because I say it's okay to use, doesn't mean I use it :p I like abbreviating with: `a = some.long.object.reference.here` and just assigning to `a`'s properties.

Comment: It's also forbidden to use in strict mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) which is a good indicator that they'll want it out of the language altogether in the future

Comment: No. Crockford shows that "so long as you understand" isn't enough; the code can have a different meaning from what you intend. If you are unfortunate enough, in your example example above, to have variables called "backgroundColor", "color" and "fontWeight", then if the expression in the parenthesis happens to evaluate to undef, the code will succeed and assign to those variables.

Answer (score 2):

In his excellent book "Javascript: The Good Parts", Douglas Crockford lists the "with Statement" in Appendix B: The Bad Parts.

He says "Unfortunately its results can sometimes be unpredictable, so it should be avoided".

He goes on to give an example, where an assignment inside the with will operate on different variables depending on whether the object is defined or not.

See [With statement considered harmful](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) (but less detailed than the explanation in the book).