# javascript function can find another function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this below code in a javascript file. When i run it i get error message :

> "Can't find variable: addZero".

```
function addZero(n) {
    return ( n < 0 || n > 9 ? "" : "0" ) + n;
}

Date.prototype.toISODate =
        new Function("with (this)\n    return " +
           "getFullYear()+'-'+ addZero(getMonth()+1)+ '-'" +
           "+ addZero(getDate()) + 'T' + addZero(getHours())+':' " +
           "+ addZero(getMinutes()) +':'+ addZero(getSeconds()) +'.000Z'");
```

Comment: I don't know what you are tying to do. but **you are doing it wrong!**

Comment: Any reason why you use `new Function` instead of defining a "normal" function? Is `addZero` in global scope? What's the context of this code?

Comment: gdoron, can you please suggest what is wrong here

Comment: @Amit. Added it as an answer, hope it'll help you out.

Comment: Regarding to `with` you might want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864026/601179)

Answer (score 1):

```
function addZero(n) {
    return ( n < 0 || n > 9 ? "" : "0" ) + n;
}

Date.prototype.toISODate = function() {
    // do what you want here
    // with real code! not strings...
}​
```

Comment: are you suggesting some thing like Date.prototype.toISODate= function()
{
 return getFullYear()+'-'+addZero(getMonth()+1)+ '-' +addZero(getDate())+'T'+addZero(getHours())+':' +addZero(getMinutes())+':'+addZero(getSeconds())+'.000Z'; 
}

Comment: @Amit. yes, something like that. But I still don't know what you're tying to do and if it's the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your quotes are off. Try

```
return "with (this)\n    return " +
getFullYear() + '-' + addZero(getMonth()+1) + '-' +
addZero(getDate()) + 'T' + addZero(getHours())+':' +
addZero(getMinutes()) +':'+ addZero(getSeconds()) +'.000Z';
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a good function on the Mozilla Javascript reference page for Date that produces ISO Date strings

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Date

```
    /* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
  function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28T19:03:12Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your Date extension like this, to keep things clear and [to avoid using the `with` keyword](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/05/avoid-javascripts-with-keyword/):

```
Date.prototype.toISODate =
  function(){

    function padLeft(nr,base,padStr){
        base = base || 10;
        padStr = padStr || '0';
        var  len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
        return len > 0? new Array(len).join(padStr)+nr : nr;
    }    

    return [this.getFullYear(),
            '-',
            padLeft(this.getMonth()+1),
            '-',
            padLeft(this.getDate()),
            'T', 
            padLeft(this.getHours()),
            ':',
            padLeft(this.getMinutes()),
            ':',
            padLeft(this.getSeconds()),
            '.',
            padLeft(this.getMilliseconds(),100),
            'Z'].join('');
  };
```

The `padLeftZero` function now exists within the scope of the `Date.toISODate` method. The use of an array literal to build the return string is for clarity. It isn't necessary and even can be called bad practice to use `new Function ...` to assign a function to `Date.prototype.toISODate`. BTW, milliseconds are added to the result (padded with zero's).