# Can comma separated expressions be used as if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

I'm trying to make sense of script which is makeing heavy use of comma-separated expressions. For example:

```
popup_window != is_null && ("function" == typeof popup_window.close && popup_window.close(), popup_window = is_null);
```

If it's true that comma separation means "evaluate all of the following expressions, then produce the value of the final expression" (as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485735/use-of-commas-versus-semicolons-in-javascript)), is this another form of an if statement?

Like:
"if popup_window is not null and popup_window.close is a method then call this method and set popup_window to null"

**Question**:
What does this statement mean and what's up with the comma separation? Is this supposed to be an if-statement?

Comment: It's just a clever (too clever) way of using AND to check a number of statements, and if they are all truthy it gets to the end where the comma is used as an operator, and if `window.close()` returns truthy (it returns the popup if one exists), the variable `popup_window` is set to `is_null`, which is probably `null` based on the statement.

Comment: So and if statement fails along the way, the final expression is not executed?

Comment: Exactly, it's like `if ( truthy && falsy && truthy )`, the last one is never checked, as the second one is falsy, and it fails then and there.

Comment: Too clever indeed... Thanks. Make it an answer?

Comment: That's a compiled, minified script. Get the source code, no one would ever write this by hand.

Comment: when you write : if(  a() && b() && c()  ) {}
a() will be tested, if a() returns true, b() will be tested, if b() returns true, c() will be tested

when you write : if(a() && b() , c() )  {} 
a() will be tested, if a() returns true b() will be tested and, c() will always be evaluated 

http://jsfiddle.net/try2d0rj/

Comment: I know people writing such code - so this doesn't need to be generated by minifiers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a series of statements really

```
popup_window != is_null // if true, continue to the statement in the parenthesis
    && 
(
    "function" == typeof popup_window.close // if true continue to close the window
      && 
    popup_window.close()
    , popup_window = is_null // this is executed as long as "popup_window != is_null" 
);                           // is truthy, it doesn't depend on the other conditions
```

assuming `is_null` is really `null`, firstly `popup_window` must not be null.
Secondly, we can assume `popup_window` is another window, opened with `window.open`, as it supposedly has to have a `close` function, and it's a bit of a Yoda condition, but it can also be written

```
typeof popup_window.close === "function"
```

so `popup_window` has to have a `close` method to continue to the next step.
The final step closes the popup window if it's not null, and if it has a `close` method.

```
popup_window.close()
```

so the other two conditions have to be truthy to get this far, there has to be a window, and it has to have a `close` method, and then that `close` method is called, and the window is closed.

And then there's the comma. From the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)**

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

and we have

```
("function" == typeof popup_window.close && popup_window.close(), popup_window = is_null);
```

lets write it a little differently

```
(                          // ↓ must be thruthy .... ↓ for this to execute
   (typeof popup_window.close === "function" && popup_window.close())
   , popup_window = is_null
);      // ↑ unrelated, it's just another operand, seperated by comma
```

The trick here is that the last part, after the comma, is always executed, as all operands seperated by the comma is evaluated.

This means that if `popup_window` is not `is_null`, `popup_window` is explicitly set to `is_null`, regardless of the second condition.

The second condition is also only exectuted it `popup_window` is not `is_null`, it then checks if there is a `close()` method, and closes the window, the statement after the comma is unrelated to the outcome of that condition.

To write it even simpler (the way it should have been written IMO)

```
if ( popup_window != is_null ) {

    if ( typeof popup_window.close === "function" ) {
        popup_window.close();
    }

    popup_window = is_null;

}
```

Comment: splendid answer. Thanks!