# What is the difference between using a comma or a semicolon to seperate lines of code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

It feels like a really silly question but i just saw some line of code here that ended with a comma ',' and **XCode** did not complain about an expected ';'

So i fooled around:

```
    float a = 1.0;
    float b = 2.0;
    float c = 3.0;

    a = b, //comma here
    c = 4.0;

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f",a,b,c);
```

The result is log is correct, but I am wondering if there is a difference as I sometimes (rarely) seem to miss the shift key when typing a semicolon.

I have read this [Use of commas versus semicolons in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485735/use-of-commas-versus-semicolons-in-javascript) but it is about javascript and i am not sure if it applies here as well.

Comment: The link you give for JavaScript is almost precisely the same as for C, including caveats. (The only difference is there is no `var` is C, so replace that with `int` for the same meaning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the C [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). It evaluates both operands and returns the result of the second, although in the case of `a = b, c = 4.0` it sets `a` equal to `b` and `c` equal to `4.0`.