# setInterval dosn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

```
function startAutoScrolling() {

     var distance = y2 - y1;
     var speed = distance / dateDiff;

     interval1 = setInterval(function() { doAutoScrolling(speed); }, 1); 

}
```

here I want to decrease step on 0.1 
but it dosn't work like that, and I don't know why

```
function doAutoScrolling(step) {

     document.getElementById(CONTEINER).scrollTop += step;

     if (isGoingDown) {
          step  = step - 0.1;
          console.log("step - 1: " + step); 
          if (step <= 0) {
               clearInterval(interval1); 
          }
     } else  {   // there is continue below
```

here I want to increase step and if condition have to stop execution of block
but it doesn`t work also

```
          step += 0.01;
          if (step >= 0) {
               clearInterval(interval1); 
          }
     } 
}
```

Comment: An what actually _is_ happening instead?

Comment: are you actually using 0,1? Should it be 0.1?

Comment: you can't use the european style `0,1` decimal system, it will result in step becoming 1. Just use the dot notation `0.1`.

Comment: I`ve changed the comma for a dot. but still dosn`t work.

there are 5000 lines "step - 1: 1.8828571428571428" in console
and it increases every 1 nanoseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the Javascript comma-operator in place where you most probably want to use a decimal, e.g.:

```
step  = step - 0,1;
```

Should be:

```
step  = step - 0.1;
```

More about the comma-operator:

- [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do)
- [When is the comma operator useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/comma-operator-where-it-can-really-be-useful)

**UPDATE** (after commas to dots -change)

Primitives are passed-by-value in Javascript (see: [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)) so you're basically calling `doAutoScrolling` over and over again with the same value (the value of `speed`). You need to do one of the following:

- wrap `speed` in an object in order to pass-by-reference
- make `speed` a global variable or at least defined in the parent context of `doAutoScrolling`
- Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` and set a new timeout in `doAutoScrolling`:

  `var newStep = /* calculate new step */`
  `setTimeout("doAutoScrolling("+newStep+")",1);`

Comment: or `step-=.1` and `step +=.01`

Comment: I did what you said neither step-=.1 nor step  -= 0.1 don`t work