# Javascript: while loop neverending

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while, do-loops

I've been trying to fix this loop, but apparently it doesn't recognize when the input is right. Am I using the right kind of loop here?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?") 
if (userChoice !== "rock", "paper", "scissors") {
  do {
    prompt("Invalid answer. Please choose rock, paper or scissors.");
  } while (userChoice !== "rock", "paper", "scissors");
} else {
```

Comment: You don't assign the result of the second `prompt()` call back to `userChoice`, so `userChoice` never changes.

Comment: ... + you're comparing against `"scissors"` only.

Comment: `userChoice !== "rock", "paper", "scissors"` isn't [doing what you think it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful)

Comment: I'm also going to preemptively guess that your next question will be why the code in the `else` block only runs when they make a correct choice first time - you probably don't need the `else` at all, with the code in that block immediately following the `if` block instead.  (unless it contains code to congratulate them on making a correct choice first time...?)

Comment: @JamesThorpe in short, the question is pretty much too broad, as good answers would have to fix all of the issues, and it's also caused by a "typo" and a partial duplicate of the question you linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 major issues here:

- You need to re-assign `userChoice` inside your `do-while` loop:

  ```
  userChoice = prompt("Invalid answer. Please choose rock, paper or scissors.");
  ```
- Your comparison is off and won't work, use this instead in your `if` and `while`:

  ```
  (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors")
  ```

Comment: An alternative is using `Array.indexOf`: `['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].indexOf('no')` (which results in `-1`)

Comment: True and thanks for that, although probably too advanced for the OP who I assume is a beginner in JS

Comment: Also probably too advanced, but regex works well here as well `var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?") ; var testrgx = /^(rock|paper|scissors)$/; if (testrgx.test(userChoice)){ } else { //while loop in here }`

Comment: @jmcgriz not only too advanced, but also less readable and probably slower than the array approach.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for the newbie question, but I was really sweating it out.

Comment: @JanDvorak regex is only less readable if you don't take the time to learn how to read it. It's a separate language all to itself, but once you spend some time with it, it's perfectly logical. As for being slower, see for yourself http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof. In chrome, the regex test function is twice as fast as index of