# JavaScript: argument list without function / parens-parens / unknown syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

What on earth is this syntax?

```
return (0, _hoistNonReactStatics2.default)(C, Component);
```

Are they specifying the function to be called inside of a parenthesis and together with a number? Why?

I have tried the following but I still don't understand what the leftmost parenthesis clause means or does.

```
> f=function(args){console.log(args)}
> (0, f)(1, 2)
1
> (f, 0)(3, 2)
TypeError: (f , 0) is not a function
```

Please help whoever can.

Answer (score -1):

It's using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which takes a comma separated list of expressions and returns the value of the last one.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful) for a valid use case.