# Async function inside forEach executes when a const declaration before

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a strange javascript behaviour that I cannot explain.
When I run

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

// const o = 2;

[1, 2, 3].forEach(async (num) => {
  await waitFor(50);
  console.log(num);
});

console.log('Done');
```

It only logs `Done`. This is expected since `forEach` cannot get async callbacks.

However if you uncomment the line `const o = 2` (`o` is not used), it logs

```
Done
1
2
3
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: Add a `;` after `waitFor = ...`

Comment: It works for me when I add a semicolon: `const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));`

Comment: @Andreas, nice catch, why is the `;` important here?

Comment: See the explanation from Kobi

Comment: @rocketer - I've added an answer explaining what is happening. I suggest you'd remove the semicolon from the question, because that was the real issue, and the question doesn't work in this form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line is missing a semicolon. Without the semicolon the code is parsed as:

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))[1,2,3].forEach( ... )
```

You can verify it if you do:

```
console.log(waitFor);
```

which prints to console the full code, and not just the first line:

```
(ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

// const o = 2;

[1, 2, 3].forEach(async (num) => {
await waitFor(50);
window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log(num);
})
```

The array declaration and `forEach` loop are contained in the lambda and are never run.

If you try to start the lambda, for example with `waitFor(6)`, the code would fail - we can see that here the comma is parsed as the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579546/7586):

```
TypeError: (new Promise(...))[3] is undefined
```