# Define Variables like a, b, c

Tags: javascript, variables, console

When I Define variables in JS like this:

```js
var a, b, c = 10;
```

I found out when call **a,b,c** this phrase (Or any other term that can be used) gives **10** value.

Now, i'm wondered and my question is what is that? and what type of this phrase? *(Returned Number in console)*

What is its use?

```js
var a, b, c = 10;

a,b,c;       //10
a,   b,c;    //10
```

Comment: Uh, that will only assign the value `10` to `c` - the rest will be `undefined` but declared.

Comment: [That is the effect of the JavaScript `comma` operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: @VLAZ I think the OP is asking why typing something like `a,b,c` into the console will print `10`. (after such a declaration)

Comment: @Pointy but...it doesn't print `10`. It prints `undefined` since it's treated as a declaration.

Comment: The question is clearer now @VLAZ.

Comment: `c;   // undefined`??? it should be `10`

Comment: @VLAZ thanks. I understood

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful

Comment: Thanks guys, I was careless

Comment: @pointy In this context the comma is used in combination with the var keyword for multiple assignments and is not the JavaScript comma operator.

Comment: @WillTaylor look at the updated question. The comma is used in the code posted both in the context of a `var` declaration *and* in the context of a simple expression typed at the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The comma has 2 different means depending on context.**

You use it in both these ways in your code sample - this is probably causing some confusion.

**1) Multiple variable assignment using var**

```
var a,b,c = 10;
```

Here the `var` keyword is used to assign multiple variables on a single line, in your case you only assign the final variable `c`, and so `a` and `b` are undefined.

Here is an example which makes its usage clearer:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

a; // 1
b; // 2
c; // 3
```

**2) JavaScript Comma Operator**

```
a,b,c; // 10
```

The [JavaScript comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates a comma separated list of expressions and returns the result of the last one.

Comment: The OP has *also* used the actual comma operator in the code posted, simply typing `a, b, c` into the console after making the `var` declaration.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Have updated my answer.