# Returning all of the specified integers from a string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The URL query after a `decodeURIComponent` and a `split()` looks like this `["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]` the results I am looking for is returning an array with the proper integer like `[1999.99]`. But there can be more than 1 price range in URL query string for example `["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]`. Which should return `[499.99, 999.99, 1999.99]`. I forgot to mention that the price positioning in the array could be different depending on the other URL queries. So that it's not always going to be guaranteed to be in the same spot.

This was the approach taken.

```
const pattern = /^price:{1,2}\[.*? TO (.*)]$/;
const price = query
  .map(q => {
    const match = pattern.exec(q);
    return match;
  });
```

Which returns this. I tried modifying the regex but unfortunately I haven't been able to get the results that I am looking  for.

```
["price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]", "1999.99", index: 0, input: "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: It's been said that the synonym for Regex is Regrets :)  Are you married to using Regex for this?   A simple function would be more readable, which is normally a high priority among seasoned developers.

Comment: What you have requested are not *integers*, but rather *floats*

Comment: @BrianPatterson No not at all, my first solution was something like this 
`const price = query.find((item) => item.match("price")).split(/::|:/)[1].split(" ")[2].replace("]", "");`. But wasn't quite able to get the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, save the string you want into a variable - then `split` off the first part (`"price"`), and then just `map` the rest with a numbers and dot matching regex, converting into a number at the end:

```js
const data = ["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"];

let str = data.find(e => e.includes("price"));

let [,...allPrices] = str.split(":");

let prices = allPrices.map(s => s.split("TO")[1].match(/[0-9\.]+/)[0]);

prices = prices.map(n => +n);

console.log(prices);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the price might not always be in the same position/index in the array depending on other data. I will update my post

Comment: Fixed @steven5210

Comment: @steven5210: Just for your notice, there is certainly [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61646519/11299053) to achieve the result with less lines and [CPU cycles](https://jsbench.me/pvka1br0en/1). Though, it might seem to [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron) the more lines, the greater is the virtue of readability, also it may give a feeling of great difficulties being overcame ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would that work for you?

```js
const arr = ["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]

      result = arr
        .find(e => e.includes('price'))
        .match(/(?<=TO )\d+\.\d+/g)
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Wow that's really good! The only issue is that it's currently an array like `["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]`. Otherwise your answer is perfect

Comment: Nevermind I just did .toString().match but is there a more efficient way without having to do a `.toString()`?

Comment: It is a valid array, and just `arr[1]` would get the string with prices in it. Though it would be unreliable if the price index isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it is basically one array with strings inside of it. Each string is separated by a comma. Sorry if it looks a bit confusing.
`["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]`

This is one string `"pcs_availability:Online"` and this is the second string in the array `"price:[250 TO 499.99]:[500 TO 999.99]:[1500 TO 1999.99]"`

Comment: @steven5210 : my bad (got to go to sleep ;), check out the latest edit

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov No problem :) Thanks for the help! Have a good sleep!

Comment: The [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579546/1218980) trick is clever, but should never be used in code intended for programmers. Let the minifier compress the code.

Comment: @EmileBergeron what would you suggest instead? It looks like eslint does not take kindly to the comma operator either so this won't pass the code linting.

Comment: `(r,str) => { r.push(...str.match(/(?<=TO )\d+\.\d+/g) || []); return r; }` on their own lines.

Comment: @EmileBergeron : *'..comma operator ....should never be used'* Comma operator is a standard well documented feature. Can't see the problem *deciphering* 2 expressions, separated by comma. One might find `reduce()` method hard to read. Does it mean it should also be sacrificed in favor of `for(..`-loop not to hurt someone's religious beliefs? What else, keep telling the Earth is flat?