# What is the difference between {;} and (,)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React.js, is there a difference between writing a function or constant as

```
const aHandler = () => {function1() ; function2();}
```

vs

```
const aHandler = () => (function1() , function2())
```

From trying these two types, it does provide the same result, but is there any other change in the back-end on how these two work? When to use one over the other?

And if there are no changes, can they be used interchangeably everywhere?

Comment: what are function1 and function2?

Comment: They provide the sane result, because both of them do nothing. Especially not calling `function1` or `function2` (at least in the form they are currently written)

Comment: 1st `aHandler` returns `undefined` and the `2nd` returns whaterver the result of `function2` is - but both otherwise perform the same function

Comment: Other than that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful might be worth reading

Comment: @JaromandaX but as it is currently written, both the callbacks wouldn't call any of `function1` or `function2`, (if they are even functions) would they?

Comment: @derpirscher - no, but what if they are variables :p perfectly valid (though completely useless) code :p - I think function*n* is just a placeholder for an actual function though

Comment: @derpirscher Sorry for the confusion. Have edited the question accordingly. Yes - they were placeholders for actual functions.

Answer (score 1):

**First Code (arrow function with curly braces)**

```
const aHandler = () => {
  function1;
  function2;
};
```

Here, when you use curly braces {}, you're creating a block of code that encapsulates multiple statements.

**Second code (Arrow Function with Parentheses):**

```
const aHandler = () => (
  function1,
  function2
);
```

With parentheses (), you're using the comma operator within parentheses. The comma operator evaluates expressions and returns the value of the last expression.

So both function will have different return type (value)