# return this || (0,eval)('this');

Tags: javascript, dot.js

Looking at the doT.js source:

https://raw.github.com/olado/doT/master/doT.js

What does this do?

```
(function(){ return this || (0,eval)('this'); }()).doT = doT;
```

To me it looks like it's creating a global var, `window.doT`. If that's all it's doing, then why not:

```
window.doT = doT;
```

?

Comment: if `this` is undefined, then why would issuing `eval('this')` help?

Comment: Because `(42,eval)` would be just plain creepy!

Comment: @TravisJ `this` doesn't have to be undefined. It could be `false` or `""` or something else falsey.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5161574/251311

Comment: Another related question: [Does the comma operator influence the execution context in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076794/does-the-comma-operator-influence-the-execution-context-in-javascript/36077031#36077031) (with an answer)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's getting a reference to the global object, in order to assign `doT` to it. This is generally done because with a JavaScript library/framework/etc, its one global identifier needs to be exposed to the *outside world*.

As for why it's not simply `window.doT = doT;`, it's because the global object isn't always `window`, for example, in a non-browser environment. It's also possible to have `window` assigned to somewhere else at the point this code is executed.

#### How it works

If `this` is already *truthy*, for example, an object such as `window`, it will return that. It's likely it will be `window` (at least in the browser), as a plain function call should have its `ThisBinding` set to the global object. Otherwise, it will execute `eval()` in the global scope because an indirect call to `eval()` will set its scope to global, as opposed to the calling environment's scope.

To achieve an indirect call, you have to invoke `eval()` indirectly, i.e. you can't just call it with `eval()`. You can use `(0, eval)` to invoke it. This relies on the comma operator returning the last evaluated expression, in this case `eval`. It doesn't matter what the preceding operands are. Similarly, `(0||eval)()` would work.

As for why the body is `this`, that is the argument to `eval()`, that is the code to be executed as a string. It will return the `this` in the global scope, which is always the global object.

It's not really relevant nowadays, but in older IEs, you'd need to use `execScript()` to execute code in the global scope. I can't remember exactly what versions of IE this was necessary for.

Comment: Why `this || (0,eval)('this')`?

Comment: By "indirect", do you mean `(0,eval)(args)`?

Comment: What would be the difference of `(0,eval)('this')` and `eval('this')` from the result point of view?

Comment: The latter would execute in the containing scope's environment, where the `ThisBinding` may be different.

Comment: If forcing `eval` to be evaluated (no pun intended) as an expression changes its scope to global, wouldn't `(eval)()` work as well?

Comment: @zerkms This is wrong, because from snippet we have a call to an anonymous function, i.e. there is no `.apply` called. I think that the only case when `this` can be undefined is when the code is called in a strict block of code ( i.e. `"use strict";` ).

Comment: @freakish: `apply` was used to set the different scope to the function call.

Comment: `(0,eval)('this')` is equivalent to `var e = eval; e('this')` as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/DBhKT/1/

Comment: Nvm on deleted comment, Alex, clear now what the counterpoint was.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, but there is no scope change in OP's code. And it cannot be because of anonymous call.

Comment: @freakish: In op's code the scope is not defined initially. I mean - you cannot be for sure what it is. While my code was to demonstrate that whatever scope you have - you'll get the `window` instance by the latter call.

Comment: @zerkms You are wrong. The scope of a holder doesn't matter, because it's an anonymous function. Unless the code is in strict mode anonymous function's `this` is always a top object. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgtnm/1/

Comment: @freakish: "anonymousity" has nothing to do with the scope. There is no difference between "anonymous" and "named" functions in how they behave. Still, I don't see your point.

Comment: @zerkms Tfu, I think I'm misusing "scope" word. One more time. What I'm saying is is that your jsFiddle changes `this` because of `.apply` call. There is no `.apply` in OP's code ( hence the question: why `this || ...` ? ). Unless there is something more between characters in this one line of code ( and it doesn't look like that ) then `this` will always be the top object unless the code is called in a strict code block ( see my jsFiddle ).

Comment: @freakish: "There is no .apply in OP's code" --- I know that. I used it to artificially change the scope to demonstrate that `eval` trick works.

Answer (score 0):

Only adding a bit to the accepted answer as the last question in the condensed comments view "wouldn't `(eval)('this')` work as well?" has its answer lost in the comment chatter. Simple test:

```
> foo = 123
< 123
> (function() { const foo = 234; console.log(
     foo,                   // baseline
     eval('foo'),           // direct eval using local scope
     (eval)('foo'),         // (eval) still direct
     (1, eval)('foo'),      // indirect by comma-operator
     (false||eval)('foo')); // indirect by or-operator
   })()
< 234 234 234 123 123
```

It shows that

- `(eval)` is not the same as `(0, eval)` (or, here, `(1,eval)`) because the comma operator is indirect whereas the parenthesis is not indirect, just a syntactic grouping, the mere parenthesis does not pass its argument through an operation, so it remains direct.
- the `(false||eval)` approach relies on the argument before being *falsy*, therefore the comma operator is better, it matters less what that first value is.

To me the comma-operator was the biggest aha here, that's why I was dwelling on it a bit.

I have a concern also, i.e., that this trick would by accident be used from a function that might be added to a prototype as a method. In that case the first `this` is no longer the global object. Which is why, to be really safe, in my opinion one should just stick with the `(0,eval)('this')` expression only.