# What does (0, eval) () do?

Tags: javascript

The following is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119988/return-this-0-evalthis/14120023#14120023)

```
function q() {
console.log((0, eval)('this'));
}
```

It returns [Object Window].

What I don't get is the (0,eval) part of this.

What is JS doing with this?

From the link, it says it is indirectly calling eval().  What does indirect mean?

Comment: My question was more about the (0,eval) part, which has now been pointed out as a use of the comma operator (which answers my question.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, just see [(1,eval)('this') vs eval('this') in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9107367/2864740), which I've now voted as a duplicate:

> .. the Ecma spec considers a reference to eval to be a "direct eval call", but an expression that merely yields eval to be an indirect one -- and indirect eval calls are guaranteed to execute in global scope.

(While the following is [mostly] true, it is *not specific* to `eval` usage.)

---

The [comma operator](http://es5.github.io/x11.html#x11.14) evaluates all the expressions and yields the value of the last expression.

That is, `(0, eval)` evaluates to `eval` (which is a function-object value), such that the resulting expression is equivalent to `eval('this')`.

To see it another way:

```
var f = (0, eval)
f === eval // true
f('this')
```