# Why wrap `eval` like this `(0, eval)`?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the evaluate function in the `systemjs` sources:

```
function evaluate (loader, source, sourceMap, address, integrity, nonce, noWrap) {
    ...
    if (useVm)
      vm.runInThisContext(...)
    else
      (0, eval)(getSource(source, sourceMap, address, !noWrap));
    postExec();
  }
```

They use `eval` to evaluate JS code but why is the `(0, eval)` construction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616264/what-does-0-eval-do

Comment: tldr :  indirect vs direct eval calls are guaranteed to execute in global rather than local scope.