# Does the comma operator influence the execution context in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, this

```
var a = 1;
var b = {
  a : 2,
  c : function () {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
};

b.c(); // logs 2
(b.c)(); // logs 2
(0, b.c)(); // logs 1
```

The first is understandable, for "this" is pointed to Object "b". But why does the second one log the same result? I thought "this" should be pointed to the global execution context. And the third one, it seems that the comma operator influences the execution context.

Comment: `this` is not an "execution context."

Comment: @Crowder Could you please explain more clearly? What I find in [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) is "The value associated with the **this** keyword within ECMAScript code associated with this execution context."

Comment: Execution contexts *have* a `this`, but the `this` is not the execution context, it's a property of it. More specifically, the *`this` binding* is a property of the execution context's *lexical environment* (or the `this` binding of an enclosing context's lexical environment, if the execution context's lexical environment doesn't have one, as happens with ES2015 arrow functions). [§8.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts) is a good place to start. Warning: The 5th edition spec was turgid, but the 2015 one is even worse. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the reason for using such syntax: `(0, _.Em)()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735424/1048572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the reason for using such syntax (0, \_.Em)();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735424/whats-the-reason-for-using-such-syntax-0-em)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You really have a nice corner case there!
My take on it:

- the first is straightforward. Just a standard call. The '.' operator lets you call the function setting `b` as the execution context.
- the second is exactly the same thing: the parens are entirely optional and the interpreter is treating the expression inside it as a bound function call. Actually I didn't expect this: I thought the interpreter would be going to reset `this` to the global object, but actually it's keeping it linked. Probably just so "casual" language users do not freak out.
- the third one is more standard (at least for those who live in JavaScript land): as soon as your function is passed on in an expression (in this case by the `,` operator) the `this` value is lost. This is because `b.c` is a `Property Reference` (deep rabbit hole details in the specification, [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation), courtesy of T.J.Crowder). So, you are actually passing around the function itself, no more bound to the declaring object. So when you call it `this` is going to be passed in as the global object.

See it this way: `(object.function)()` gets simplyfied into `object.function()`, because the enclosing parens are completely optional; `(0, object.function)()` is parsed as `(expression yielding a function)()` which is going to lose the `object` binding to `this`, because function is already unbound.

Really nice example!

Comment: Good update, although *"as soon as your function is passed on in an expression (in this case by the , operator) the this value bound to the execution context is lost"* is still incorrect: We're not using `this`, we're using `b`, and the mechanism by which the object reference doesn't end up being used is because the property reference isn't directly used to make the call. Details in [§12.3.4.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Answer (score 19):

Refer to [Indirect eval call](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/), which gives more details about it.

```
 (     0        ,          b.c   )        (  )
     |____|   |_____|    |_____|
     Literal  Operator   Identifier

     |_________________________|
     Expression

  |______________________________|
  PrimaryExpression

  |______________________________|        |________|
  MemberExpression                        Arguments

  |________________________________________________|

  CallExpression
```

We can use the comma operator to fashion an indirect call to `b.c` which will force it to execute in the `global context`, the value of `a` is `1` in the `global context`.

Also the result of `(b.c = b.c)()` is `1`

```
> (b.c = b.c)()
  1
```

> Speaking in terms of ECMAScript, this is because both — comma operator (in `(0, b.c)` example) and `=` operator (in `(b.c = b.c)` example) perform GetValue on its operands.

Other indirect call formats as below

```
> (b.c, b.c)()
  1 
> (1? b.c: 0)()
  1
> (__ = b.c)()
  1
```