# Are parentheses ignored if they only contain a property accessor?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Given the following code, why doesn't `(obj.foo)()` receive `window` as `this`? It seems to me like the parentheses are ignored, rather than treated as an expression that evaluates to `foo`?

```js
window.bar = 'window';
const obj = { bar: 'obj' };

obj.foo = function() {
  console.log(`Called through ${this.bar}`);
}

obj.foo(); // Called through obj

(obj.foo)(); // Called through obj - Why?

(0, obj.foo)(); // Called through window

(true && obj.foo)(); // Called through window
```

Comment: Here you can probably find a good explanation of the same behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076794/does-the-comma-operator-influence-the-execution-context-in-javascript/36077031#36077031

Comment: Good question, well asked.

Comment: @A.Chiesa - I didn't realize from your comment that that's a good dupetarget for this. Marked it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, the wording is quite different, even if the concepts are exactly the same. I think I'm going to update the answer with the _Reference_ explanation

Comment: Well today I learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not *ignored*, but the result of `(obj.foo)` is the same [Reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reference-specification-type) (specification term) as the result of `obj.foo` (see [this section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the spec). So the [property accessor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors) has the same information to work with to get the object and property and to use that object as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Cause `obj.foo` evaluates to a *Reference* that contains `obj` and `"foo"`. When you [[Call]] the reference, both `obj` and `foo` are known as part of the Reference.

Most operators (including the comma operator) evaluate the Reference to a value.