# Javascript: what does this syntax mean (0,functionName)(functionParemeter);

Tags: javascript

I was wondering into the javascript file from the source of http://www.google.com actually i do it often and try to understand what they have done there. today I was wondering inside the files and found some strange function calls. Maybe its a silly thing but I really have no idea what is it and so that I couldn't help by searching for it.

a readable resemble of the code-

```
var someFunction = function(somaeParamenter){
    //do some stuffs;
    return something;
}

var someOtherThing = (0, someFunction)(oneParameter);
```

Please excuse my lack of knowledge.

**EDIT:**

Source-

i'm using chrome.
while in the http://www.google.com page open, i opened the developer tool. then i opened the sources tab and opened the file `https://www.google.com.bd/xjs/_/js/s/c,sb,cr,cdos,vm,tbui,mb,wobnm,cfm,abd,bihu,kp,lu,m,tnv,amcl,erh,hv,lc,ob,r,rsn,sf,sfa,shb,srl,tbpr,hsm,j,p,pcc,csi/rt=j/ver=WUW4ydIf-wI.en_US./am=gA/d=1/sv=1/rs=AItRSTPu52CumknQsh0was81vrM4inla_w` in viewer. this file is the only js file i've seen there. I enabled the "pretty print" and in line 58 you'll find the defination-

```
_.Va = function(a) {
            var b = typeof a;
            if ("object" == b)
                if (a) {
                    if (a instanceof window.Array)
                        return "array";
                    if (a instanceof window.Object)
                        return b;
                    var c = window.Object.prototype.toString.call(a);
                    if ("[object Window]" == c)
                        return "object";
                    if ("[object Array]" == c || "number" == typeof a.length && "undefined" != typeof a.splice && "undefined" != typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable && !a.propertyIsEnumerable("splice"))
                        return "array";
                    if ("[object Function]" == c || "undefined" != typeof a.call && "undefined" != typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable && !a.propertyIsEnumerable("call"))
                        return "function"
                } else
                    return "null";
            else if ("function" == b && "undefined" == typeof a.call)
                return "object";
            return b
        };
```

and in line 83 you'll see the function is called.

```
_.Za = function(a) {
            return "array" == (0, _.Va)(a)
        };
```

Comment: Can you cite the exact source, please? I cannot find it in what I get delivered at `http://www.google.com/`

Comment: Side note: Google's JS is heavily optimized and minified so it's probably not the best place to take influences from.

Comment: @Juhana you are right but i can't resist myself from peeking there :)

Comment: @bergi i've edited my question citing the source.

Comment: is this simply a comma operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator

Comment: @maksbd19: Thanks! Yes, it's the comma operator, and it seems pretty useless here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(0, someFunction)
```

simply returns `someFunction`

so this is just equivalent to

```
var someOtherThing = someFunction(oneParameter);
```

Are you sure you typed it exactly as it was ? If so, and if it wasn't some kind of obfuscation, then it might be the unfortunate result of some minification. If the real code were a little different, for example `(0, someObject.someFunction)` , there might be some use of this [indirect function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161502/indirect-function-call-in-javascript).

EDIT :

You edit confirms that it the goal was probably to ensure that `this`, inside the function, is the global object (`window` in a browser) and not the object on which `Va` was attached (`_`).

Comment: Instead of `0`, they probably had an assignment or function call or any other expression.

Comment: `(Potato, I think) it is the result of obfuscation.`

Comment: There is one delicate exception where they are not equal: [`(0, eval)(…)`](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/#evaling_in_global_scope)

Comment: @Bergi That's an interesting point. Calling the function indirectly maybe was the goal here but I don't see how it could be useful with the code we see.