# Calling JavaScript function with the syntax (0, myFunction)()

Tags: javascript

I'm very new in the JavaScript, but I found the syntax `(0, myFunction)()` to call anonymous functions on JavaScript, but I don't know what means the 0 before the anonymous function, also I don't know if instead of 0 I can use 1 or 2, etc.

Basically my question is what is the difference between call a function `myFuntion()` or `(0, myFunction)()`. The function is in a global context.

Here is an example.

```
var object = {}
object.foo = function(){}
```

The difference between call the function

```
(0,object.foo)();
```

or

```
object.foo();
```

Comment: Please provide more context. `(0, myFunction)` by itself doesn't do anything (it certainly doesn't execute a function).

Comment: Where did you see this?  In what context?  Can you post an example?

Comment: You sure it had the outer parens? It makes a little more sense without them.

Comment: ...I assume you saw `(0, function() { /* some code */ }())`, but then the `0,` seems pointless. This however is a little different `0, function() { /* some code */ }()`

Comment: Or how about this: `"invoke"<-function() { /* some code */ }()`

Comment: With your edit of adding (), it just made it a little more clearer. Now you can read about the comma operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indirect function call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161502/indirect-function-call-in-javascript)

Comment: The comma "operator" yields the last value which, in this case, is the function ... calling it will drop the `this` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite both calls into the following equivalents:

```
object.foo.call(null); // (0,object.foo)();

object.foo.call(foo); // object.foo();
```

As you can see, the only difference is the "binding" of `this` inside the called function; but the use of `(0, something)();` is considered as cryptic and should be avoided in a professional code base.