# How does javascript determine `this` in this context?

Tags: javascript, this

Let's say we have an object with a function property, and this function uses `this`:

```
let o = {
  a: function() {
    return `a, ${this.b}`;
  },
  b: 'b'
};
```

I understand that we'll see `'a, b'` for the following piece of code:

```js
let o = { a: function() { return `a, ${this.b}`; }, b: 'b' };
console.log(o.a());
```

This is because javascript considers the in-place "topology" of `o.a(...)` to mean that `o` ought to be set as `this` within this occurence of `o.a`'s execution.

I also understand that the following produces `'a, undefined'`:

```js
let o = { a: function() { return `a, ${this.b}`; }, b: 'b' };
let f = o.a;
console.log(f());
```

This is because the "topology" of `f(...)` tells javascript that there is no explicit `this`.

For this reason I was surprised that the following produces `'a, b'`:

```js
let o = { a: function() { return `a, ${this.b}`; }, b: 'b' };
console.log((o.a)());
```

It looks to me like using parentheses around `(o.a)` should force javascript to resolve `o.a` to an unbound, `this`-less function, before going any further.

For completeness, this example successfully unbinds the instance of the function call:

```js
let o = { a: function() { return `a, ${this.b}`; }, b: 'b' };
let f = () => 'f';
console.log((o.a || f)());
```

Even though the `||` short-circuits on the first operand, there's still a difference between `(o.a)` and `(o.a || f)`.

- How should I comprehend javascript's logic to determine the value of `this`?
- Are there any other unintuitive examples related to these?
- Is there any better or more official vocabulary I can use to describe what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: `(o.a)` doesn't really do anything.  The function `a` still belongs to the object `o`

Comment: `(o.a)` === `o.a` - the two are literally the same, just like `1 + (2)` is no different in any way to `1 + 2`

Comment: Well, I could also say that for `let f = <something>;`, `f` is always exactly equivalent to `<something>` - but in this case it isn't, as the `this` context disappears

Comment: The exact semantics are all explained in soporific detail in the spec, if you want to really get the full story.

Comment: @GershomsupportsMonica I don't think you got it: `o.a()` is *literally* the same as `(o.a)()` - there is no difference between the two in any way shape or form. Your expectation is incorrect as `(o.a)` isn't going to lose the context. However, if you have a different expression like `(o.a || f)()` or `(0, o.a)()` that's not the same case as before.

Comment: The simple answer is that the context is retained whenever `o.a` is called directly, rather than being saved in a temporary or variable. Putting parentheses around it doesn't make it a temporary, but using it as part of an expression does.

Comment: The canonical way to remove the context is `(1, o.a)()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161502/indirect-function-call-in-javascript

Comment: Ah, so it's almost like under certain conditions js will decide to treat parenthesized code as if it isn't parenthesized at all? (As opposed to "remembering that parenthesization happened, but also somehow keeping track of `this`-context for some duration"?)

Comment: As much as it may not seem like it at first, the value of `this` is actually fairly intuitive. The difference lies in the fact that when you assign functions to other variables you need to provide a context using `bind` or it will default to either `undefined` or `window`. a.e. `let f = o.a;` leads to an **undefined** context. `let f = o.a.bind( o );` leads to the context of **o**

Comment: @GershomsupportsMonica parentheses don't do the same thing every time. It depends on what's inside them, so JS doesn't "decide" that parentheses are irrelevant but rather that the expression inside will have different results based on the *expression itself*. Removing the parentheses in `1 + (2)` will have no effect but with `(1 + 2) * 3` there *will* be a difference.

Comment: You're thinking way too hard about parentheses. They're not magic. It's order of operations when parsing the code. Parentheses are evaluated first.

Comment: @zfrisch I guess that's the main thing I'm asking about - it really seems like `(o.a)` *isn't* evaluated first, as it resolves to a `this`-less function.

Comment: `(o.a)()` -> `o.a()` -> the method `a` is executed with `o` as `this`.

Comment: If we do `let ts = 'abc'.toString`, then calling `ts()` is *not* the same as calling `'abc'.toString()`! There is a difference based on whether the js parser can find a `this` value inline. To me it is strange that `('abc'.toString)()` behaves like `'abc'.toString()`, and not `ts`, as the parenthesization requires us to resolve the value of `'abc'.toString` before performing a function call on the result. It seems like the parentheses are not resolved first, though they should have precedence.