# Different ways of declaring a method on a JavaScript ES6 class?

Tags: javascript

I finally got fed up with being confused about and just tested the following three snippets:

```
class A {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  calcArea = function() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  calcArea = () => {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

class C {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

As you can see, each class uses a different syntax to declare its `calcArea` function. I understand well the difference between normal functions and fat arrow functions with regards to lexical scoping vs dynamic scoping, but I don't see any difference in this case. In all three cases, the result of `calcArea` is as expected. In all three cases, `this` correctly points to the instance of the class.

It's also unclear to me whether the syntax in class C is a shortcut for A or for B.

Is there any difference between declaring methods in these different ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: Difference between first two: `(1, new A(4, 4).calcArea)();`, difference between second two: `new A().hasOwnProperty("calcArea")`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte not sure I follow that first example....what is `1` being passed to?

Comment: nothing, it's just the shortest way i know to generate an indirect call, to remove the object reference for `this`. If you want it longer, add an intermediate variable: `let f = new A(4, 4).calcArea; f();`. If you do the same for `B`, you'll get different results. This difference is well explained in the suggested dupe link btw, the difference between `A` (or `B`, along with the previous) and `C` is mainly, whether it's on the prototype or an instance method.

Comment: I see the difference between the first two, by executing your example, but I don't understand it. `a = new A(4,4); a.calcArea()` still works....how have you removed the reference? how could that realistically happen?

Comment: E.g. by passing the function as a callback. See [how-does-the-this-keyword-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). As mentioned, you should also read the suggested dupe target, it elaborates on the difference between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Note for my future self: the meaning of ASDFGerte's first example is more clearly represented by `a = new A(4, 4); y = a.calcArea; y();` and then the same thing with `B`. I get it now Gerte, thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i chose that way out of habit, but it probably creates additional confusion, when not having been seen before. As a side reference, here is an [explanation for the comma operator used for indirect function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161502/indirect-function-call-in-javascript). It's just a very short way to do it.

Comment: `C` should be equivalent to `A` and will be using dynamic scoping, while `B` is different and will be using lexical scoping.